# How to write non correlated query with inner join in sql for this question?

Tags: mysql, sql

on the basis of country I want list of suppliers that has more than one suppliers and from such suppliers I want those who has product(can be any one) price less than 20.

suppliers table :

```
supplier_name  id  country
A               1   germany
B               2   london 
C               3   london 
D               4   germany
```

Products table :

```
products  price  id
onion      30    1
tomato     20    1
potato     3     1
pulses     60    2
rice       18    2
spice     100    2
jacket    300    3
fruits     8     4
```

My sql query for this question :

```
select id, 
       supplier_name, 
       count(country) as sd , 
       ( select distinct  s.id
         from suppliers s 
         inner join products p on s.id=p.id 
         where price<20) as d 
from suppliers
group by country
having sd > 1;
```

This is my query
but column d and sd is printed as extra column which I don't need

can anyone help me to write the better non-correlated query with inner join ?

I want list of suppliers where a country has more than one suppliers
and from such suppliers I want those who has product(can be any one) price less than 20.

Look at the above suppliers table where germany has two suppliers A, D which is more than one and from such suppliers I want those who has product(can be any one) price less than 20.

so the output will be :

```
suppliers_name     id    
    A               1    
    B               2     
    D               4
```

Comment: *on the basis of country greater than 3 choose the supplier_name from suppliers table and in products table for any products price must be greater than 20.* I read it three times, but I don't understand anything...

Comment: Please clarify by adding desired output as text to the question.

Comment: Your design looks wrong. I would have expected a linking table to relate suppliers to products.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: And sd is also an extra column you don't need (according to your specification)

Comment: To clarify you want a list of suppliers that sell in more than 1 country and the products they sell that cost less than 20 is that correct?  Or do you just want the supplier names that sell in more than 1 country and have products under 20?

Comment: @ Bee_Rii   I do not want  list of suppliers that sell in more than 1 country  but  I want  list of suppliers where a country has more than one suppliers.

Comment: @ Bee_Rii  Look  at the above suppliers table where germany has two suppliers A, D which is more than one and from such suppliers I want those who has  product(can be any one) price less than 20.

Comment: Your query really has nothing to do with answering the question.  The query itself is not even proper SQL, because the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` columns are inconsistent.  It is really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  can u explain me how query is inconsistent? Can I know what is unclear in above question?

Comment: @rishabjain . . . You have `GROUP BY country` but `SELECT id, supplier_name`.  That is not how `GROUP BY` works.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The query executes successfully, but I want a better query as in my case column name d and sd are extra column which I don't want. It is a non correlated query so inner query executes first and after that the outer query executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query fails miserably in Access which is only query engine I have. Consider:

```
SELECT id, supplier_name 
FROM Suppliers INNER JOIN (
        SELECT country, Count(ID) AS CntID
        FROM Suppliers GROUP BY country) AS C
ON Suppliers.country = c.country
WHERE CntID>1 AND id IN (SELECT supID FROM Products WHERE price<20)
ORDER BY ID;
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT Suppliers.id, Suppliers.supplier_name
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN (Suppliers INNER JOIN (SELECT country, Count(ID) AS CntID
                                  FROM Suppliers GROUP BY country) AS C 
            ON Suppliers.country = C.country) 
ON Products.supID = Suppliers.ID
WHERE C.[CntID]>1 AND Products.price<20;
```

I renamed id in Products to supID.

Comment: Thanku @June7 this was exactly what I wanted .